# Как в QSS прописать путь к изображению для стрелок в QScrollArea?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qss, qscrollarea

Пытался сделать таблицу стиля для виджета `QScrollArea`. 
Заметил, что можно изменить внешний вид стрелок, которые находятся по краям полос прокрутки. Для этого нужно прописать путь к нужным изображениям.

Я видел пример, но к сожалению, плохо пониманию, как он устроен: 
`border-image: url(./images/right_arrow.png);`.

Предполагаю, что `./images` - это папка в текущей папке, но когда прописал таким образом путь к изображению, которое лежит в моей текущей папке, ничего не получилось: 
`border-image: url(./picture1.png);`.

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как правильно указать путь к стрелкам на краях полос прокрутки? 
Какой оптимальный размер нужно выбирать для изображения, которое в дальнейшем должно стать такой стрелкой? 
Можно ли удалить эти стрелки с полос прокрутки?

**main.py:**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setMinimumSize(250, 150)

        scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
        scrollArea.setStyleSheet('''QScrollArea {
                                        border-style: hidden;
                                        border-image: url(./picture1.png);
                                    }''') # <----------------------
        content_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        scrollArea.setWidget(content_widget)
        scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.box1 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(content_widget)        

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button')

        for n in range(1, 17):
            btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(
                f'Button{n}',
                clicked=lambda ch, n=n: print(f'Button{n}')
            )
            self.box1.addWidget(btn, n-1, 0)

        self.box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.box.addWidget(scrollArea)

        self.box.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(self.box)


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        import sys
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        window = MyWindow()
        window.setWindowTitle(' ')
        window.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для наглядности я создал **ДВА** виджета `QScrollArea` и применил к ним **разные** таблицы стилей.

Обратите внимание, что для `scrollArea_2` я дал имя объекта **`'scrollArea_2'`**

```
scrollArea_2.setObjectName('scrollArea_2')
```

которое использую во **второй** таблице стилей именно для этого объекта

```
#scrollArea_2 QScrollBar:horizontal {...}
```

---

Примеры таблиц стилей Qt и др. смотрим:

https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qscrollbar

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html

---

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setMinimumSize(250, 150)

        scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()

        # скрыть горизонтальную полосу прокрутки
        scrollArea.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)   # +++

        content_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        scrollArea.setWidget(content_widget)
        scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.box1 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(content_widget)        

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button')

        for n in range(1, 17):
            btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(
                f'Button{n}',
                clicked=lambda ch, n=n: print(f'Button{n}')
            )
            self.box1.addWidget(btn, n-1, 0)

# ++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        scrollArea_2 = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
        scrollArea_2.setObjectName('scrollArea_2')                              # +++
        content_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        scrollArea_2.setWidget(content_widget)
        scrollArea_2.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.box1 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(content_widget)        

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button')

        for n in range(1, 17):
            btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(
                f'Button{n}',
                clicked=lambda ch, n=n: print(f'Button{n}')
            )
            self.box1.addWidget(btn, n-1, 0)

#++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    

        self.box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.box.addWidget(scrollArea)

        self.box.addWidget(scrollArea_2)

        self.box.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(self.box)


Stylesheet = ("""
QScrollBar:vertical {              
    border: none;
    background: white;
    width: 3px;               
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
QScrollBar::handle:vertical {
    background: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0,
    stop: 0 rgb(32, 47, 130), stop: 0.5 rgb(32, 47, 130), stop:1 rgb(32, 47, 130));
    min-height: 0px;
}
QScrollBar::add-line:vertical {
    background: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0,
    stop: 0 rgb(32, 47, 130), stop: 0.5 rgb(32, 47, 130),  stop:1 rgb(32, 47, 130));
    height: 0px;
    subcontrol-position: bottom;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical {
    background: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0,
    stop: 0  rgb(32, 47, 130), stop: 0.5 rgb(32, 47, 130),  stop:1 rgb(32, 47, 130));
    height: 0 px;
    subcontrol-position: top;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}


/* ------------------------  scrollArea_2  QScrollBar  -------------------------------
vvvvvvvvvvvvv                                                                        */
#scrollArea_2 QScrollBar:horizontal {
    height: 15px;
    margin: 3px 15px 3px 15px;
    border: 1px transparent #2A2929;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: yellow;    
}
#scrollArea_2 QScrollBar::handle:horizontal {
    background-color: blue;      
    min-width: 5px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
#scrollArea_2 QScrollBar::add-line:horizontal {
    margin: 0px 3px 0px 3px;
    border-image: url(./images/right_arrow_disabled.png);       
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    subcontrol-position: right;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
#scrollArea_2 QScrollBar::sub-line:horizontal {
    margin: 0px 3px 0px 3px;
    border-image: url(./images/left_arrow_disabled.png);        
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    subcontrol-position: left;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
#scrollArea_2 QScrollBar::add-line:horizontal:hover,QScrollBar::add-line:horizontal:on {
    border-image: url(./images/right_arrow.png);               
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    subcontrol-position: right;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
#scrollArea_2 QScrollBar::sub-line:horizontal:hover, QScrollBar::sub-line:horizontal:on
{
    border-image: url(./images/left_arrow.png);               
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    subcontrol-position: left;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
#scrollArea_2 QScrollBar::up-arrow:horizontal, QScrollBar::down-arrow:horizontal {
    background: none;
}
#scrollArea_2 QScrollBar::add-page:horizontal, QScrollBar::sub-page:horizontal {
    background: none;
}
#scrollArea_2 QScrollBar:vertical {
    background-color: #2A2929;
    width: 15px;
    margin: 15px 3px 15px 3px;
    border: 1px transparent #2A2929;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
#scrollArea_2 QScrollBar::handle:vertical {
    background-color: red;         
    min-height: 5px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
#scrollArea_2 QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical {
    margin: 3px 0px 3px 0px;
    border-image: url(./images/up_arrow_disabled.png);        
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    subcontrol-position: top;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
#scrollArea_2 QScrollBar::add-line:vertical {
    margin: 3px 0px 3px 0px;
    border-image: url(./images/down_arrow_disabled.png);       
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    subcontrol-position: bottom;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
#scrollArea_2 QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical:hover,QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical:on {
    border-image: url(./images/up_arrow.png);                 
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    subcontrol-position: top;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
#scrollArea_2 QScrollBar::add-line:vertical:hover, QScrollBar::add-line:vertical:on {
    border-image: url(./images/down_arrow.png);                
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    subcontrol-position: bottom;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
#scrollArea_2 QScrollBar::up-arrow:vertical, QScrollBar::down-arrow:vertical {
    background: none;
}
#scrollArea_2 QScrollBar::add-page:vertical, QScrollBar::sub-page:vertical {
    background: none;
}
""")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    app.setStyleSheet(Stylesheet)                       

    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**right_arrow_disabled.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**left_arrow_disabled.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**right_arrow.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**left_arrow.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**up_arrow_disabled.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**down_arrow_disabled.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**up_arrow.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**down_arrow.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбирать